# How to prove this theorem of $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ non empty set. Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ both are $\sigma$-algebra on E, and $A\in\tau$. If $A\in \tau_1$ and $A\in \tau_2$. Prove that $\tau$ is also $\sigma$-algebra.

I have try to answer it.

$\tau_1$ is $\sigma$-algebra, so $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty P_n\in \tau_1, \forall P_n\in \tau_1$.

$\tau_2$ is $\sigma$-algebra, so $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty Q_n\in \tau_2, \forall Q_n\in \tau_2$.

Because of $A\in \tau_1$ and $A\in \tau_2$, $A\in \tau_1\cup\tau_2$. $\tau_1\cup\tau_2$ is also $\sigma$-algebra.

Because $A\in \tau$ and $A\in \tau_1\cup\tau_2$, so $\tau$ is also $\sigma$-algebra.

But I'm not sure with my answer. Please anyone correct my answer if wrong.. Thanks

Comment: The phrase "If $A\in \tau_1$, $A\in \tau_2$, and $A\in \tau$" is very confusing. Do you perhaps mean to say that $\tau$ is the intersection of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$? That is, $\tau$ consists of all $A$ which are in both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$?

Comment: Are you defining $\tau$ as $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$?

Comment: Also, it is not in general true that $\tau_1\cup \tau_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. However, $\tau_1\cap \tau_2$ is.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, I want to say $A\in\tau_1\cap\tau_2$. Please see my edited question above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove Intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra and the powerset is a $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657187/prove-intersection-of-sigma-algebras-is-a-sigma-algebra-and-the-powerset-i)

Comment: To see how your question is covered by the linked question, let the collection $\{\mathcal A_i\}$ equal $\{\tau_1,\tau_2\}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for your help.